# How to return data from VT by stored procedure in Teradata?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, teradata

I have a stored procedure without parameters. How I can return results/data from `VT` created there?

I would like procedure to return:

```
select * from VT
```

I don't know how to implement cursors there..

Any suggestions?

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_()
BEGIN
DECLARE VT_CREATE VARCHAR(10000);
SET VT_CREATE = 'CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT
(
      A DECIMAL(38,0),
      B BIGINT
) NO PRIMARY INDEX ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;';
CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQL(VT_CREATE);

BEGIN
DECLARE VT_INSERT LONG VARCHAR;
SET VT_INSERT = 'INSERT INTO VT SEL 1, 2;';

CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQL(VT_INSERT);


END;
END;
```

Comment: [Creating a Stored Procedure and Returning Result Sets to the Caller or Client](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/zzfV8dn~lAaKSORpulwFMg/iJLs_ICS1uy5sMPbMy4KiQ)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this do the same thing?

```
create macro mc_1
as (
  select cast( 1 as decimal(38,0) ) , cast( 2 as bigint);
)  
;

exec mc_1;
```